# How To Filter Recurring Last 3 months from a specific start date?

Tags: filters

My company uses salesforce and have introduced OTE targets determined every 3 months. This started in May 2018.

I want a filter that displays the current OTE data. The commands 'LAST 3 MONTHS'. 'LAST 13 WEEKS', 'LAST QUARTER' do not work as it includes data from previous OTE's. LAST QUARTER would work if I could specify a starting date of May 2018 for it.

For example

```
In August 2018, I want to see entries for August 2018
In September 2018, I want to see entries for August & September 2018
In October 2018, I want to see entries for August, September & October 2018
In November 2018, I want to see entries for November 2018
In December 2018, I want to see entries for November & December 2018
etc...
```

I am only a standard user, not a system admin so only have access to the following as shown below. I can get what I want by specifying a start and end date, but this is not ideal as it will require manual changing every 3 months.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're willing to redefine your fiscal quarters (such that they start in May or something), you'd need a formula. I think the following formula should just about work:

```
This OTE Period (Checkbox) =

FLOOR((YEAR(TODAY())*12)+(MONTH(TODAY())-1)/3) <=
(YEAR(CreatedDate)*12)+((MONTH(CreatedDate)-1)/3)
```

And from there, you can create a list view/report with criteria like the following:

```
Created Date equals LAST 3 MONTHS AND
This OTE Period equals TRUE
```

You may need to adjust things slightly, but this should give you a high performance list view (the Created Date filter narrows down the list of records the formula has to check) while giving you the data you're looking for.